# How do I create a Kakoune colorscheme?

Tags: color-scheme, kakoune

I'm trying the [Kakoune](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune) editor and I can't find any colorscheme that I like available for it on the internet. Is it hard to create a Kakoune colorscheme? Maybe I could port one of the vim ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found https://delapouite.github.io/kakoune-ink/ to be super useful and it has solved all my problems.

It's a web-app that allows you to point and click on keywords and classes of words then select colors for them, with the resulting colorscheme being shown in a kakoune-like window. Then you can export your color selections as a "colorscheme".

Just grab the output and save it in a file in your "colors" directory (it's probably at `~/.config/kak/colors/`, you can just create this directory if it doesn't exists).